# What could be causing problems on pinging Windows 8 machines?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, ping, icmp

Here at my job I have five machines with Windows 8 Consumer Preview installed on it. Today I was testing the network conectivity and any of the five machines answered to a [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) ping request (but from another way, they are OK on pinging a Windows 7 system). So, I changed the switch, tested on another network that have one machine with Windows 8 and the same problem, no ping responses from Windows 8 (even pinging from Windows 7 to Windows 8 machine didn't work).

Is someone else having problems on pinging Windows 8 machines?

Does Microsoft disabled ping on Windows 8?

It is a installable feature now(such as Telnet Client)?

Should this be a problem related to the embedded network drivers on Windows 8?

Comment: What is the state of the firewall on those machines?

Comment: All of them are fresh-installed. I just installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview, booted and created a user for them. The firewall configs/state are just the defaults.

Comment: I don't have a windows 8 install to look at so I have no idea what the defaults are. Have you tried turning the firewall off on one then pinging it?

Comment: No, I haven't, just a sec I will try now.

Comment: Wow, that is it, Windows 8 Consumer Preview comes with ping requests disabled by default. Disabling Firewall allowed ping responses... This behavior wasn't pronounced on Windows 7.

Comment: I only thought of it because our W7 firewall here blocks ping requests.

Comment: I never seen this before on Windows 7.... I don't know if all machines that I already worked with Windows 7 had Windows Firewall disabled... Everytime I install a windows 7, the first thing I usually do is disable Windows Firewal... What I didn't now with these Windows 8 machines....

Comment: Let us start by using the Release Preview. Confirm the problem is perhaps not with the Consumer Preview. The Windows Firewall is on by default ever since Windows XP SP2.  I don't know you build your images to deploy on your machines but by default the firewall in Windows 7 would be on by default.

Comment: Right now I'm downloading it :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The firewall will block ping requests depending on its configuration. By default, Windows 8 Consumer Preview comes with ping requests blocked by Windows Firewall. Disabling or ajusting Windows Firewall will allow ping responses...

Also, there is a How-to-Geek article specifically about it:

[How to Enable Ping Echo Replies in Windows 8](http://www.howtogeek.com/77132/how-to-enable-ping-echo-replies-in-windows-8/)